# preoverride extension files by customized theme

Tags: extensions, overrides

we installed fresh magento site , everything was working fine

the "add to cart" button was calling from addtocart.phtml file under

```
app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

but later we added an extension, than addtocart button calling from

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/extension_name/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

extension addtocart.phtml is overwriting the current addtocart.phtml file

please help what i have to do to override the extension file by normal addtocart.phtml file

Comment: Delete it? It should fallback to the "default" magento file. BUT, functionalities added by your extension might be lost. What is the extension you're talking about?

Comment: @JulienLachal the extension is related to multivendor site , its required.....

Comment: multivendor site? what do you mean?

Comment: its an marketplace extension - seller can sell their products in site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make copy of your extension `addtocart.phtml` and place it in you theme.

i.e.

> /app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/extension_name/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Then do your changes in above file as you did in `app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`. So won't affect the extension functionality.

Or else as **@Julien Lachal** said, delete that extension file(`addtocart.phtml`).

Comment: i will try this.....

Comment: no no no, I didn't say to delete the extension good sir, I merely suggested that he deletes the .phtml, maybe that wasn't clear :p

Comment: @JulienLachal updated